# JSON Loop flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have trouble getting data from a complex json, below is the json in the request.i would like to display all comments under publication object

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": {
        "message": "Détails de publication"
    },
    "publication": [
        {
            "id": 47,
            "user_id": 4,
            "name": "spadrilles",
            "description": "deux spadrille presque neufs",
            "category": "Bijoux",
            "quantity": 0,
            "size": "XS 32",
            "brand": "ZARA",
            "for_who": "homme",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "delivery": "disponible le 25-01-2020",
            "price": "150.5",
            "progression": 0,
            "discount": "5",
            "visibility": 0,
            "status": "Presque Neuf",
            "softdelete": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-01-06T14:51:27.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-22T10:26:39.000000Z",
            "picture1": "b7c992f0ac7b0edd7e7e5ee12e617d9c07411b4d343f64f1caf94aa08d08b8fc.jpg",
            "picture2": "efdffb16f47e0ab40788b760ab9154fc95a1fded8f6963b227aceaff302e8623.png",
            "picture3": "8e23d6ec620353c8802bb969836b5d80f6c871fdc419f695a7c1da0e71e378ff.png",
            "picture4": null,
            "picture5": "5f3eac05c317d25cd0d691d545236fb0ef6059870217ea50dfd45b914d997d82.png",
            "comment": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "pub_id": 47,
                    "user_id": 21,
                    "comment": "test test testsssssssssssst",
                    "created_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:32.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:32.000000Z",
                    "username": "occasion_saly",
                    "user_picture": "1611217814.png"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "pub_id": 47,
                    "user_id": 21,
                    "comment": "test test testsssssssssssst",
                    "created_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:36.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:36.000000Z",
                    "username": "occasion_saly",
                    "user_picture": "1611217814.png"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "pub_id": 47,
                    "user_id": 21,
                    "comment": "test test testsssssssssssst",
                    "created_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:37.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:37.000000Z",
                    "username": "occasion_saly",
                    "user_picture": "1611217814.png"
                }
            ],
            "ownerpicture": "1608970983.png"
        }
    ],
    "error": {},
    "status": 200
}
```

As you can see, under publication there are comment object and under those they have 3 comments.i want to display it all using for loop .

Kindly assist.

my code (usually dislay one comment):

```
 @override
          void initState() {
            getproduct(widget.idproduct);
            super.initState();
          }
        
          Future<dynamic> getproduct(int id) async {
            var response = await Network().getData('/publication/show/$id');
            
            data = json.decode(response.body)['publication'];
            
            inspect(data);
            return data;
          }

 

    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: getproduct(widget.idproduct),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++)
                                CommentsList(
                                  comment: snapshot.data[i]['comment'][i]
                                      ['comment'],
                                  username: snapshot.data[i]['comment'][i]
                                      ['username'],
                                  user_picture:
                                      "${snapshot.data[i]['comment'][i]['user_picture']}",
                                )
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert json to Your Entity and use it
You can use this site for [Json to Dart code](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Here code to convert json to Model

```
Response response=await http.get(url);
return YourDataEntity.fromJson(jsonDecode(resposne.body));
```

Here your entity

```
class YourDataEntity {
    int code;
    Message message;
    List<Publication> publication;
    Error error;
    int status;

    YourDataEntity({this.code, this.message, this.publication, this.error, this.status});

    YourDataEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        code = json['code'];
        message = json['message'] != null ? new Message.fromJson(json['message']) : null;
        if (json['publication'] != null) {
            publication = new List<Publication>();
            json['publication'].forEach((v) { publication.add(new Publication.fromJson(v)); });
        }
        error = json['error'] != null ? new Error.fromJson(json['error']) : null;
        status = json['status'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['code'] = this.code;
        if (this.message != null) {
      data['message'] = this.message.toJson();
    }
        if (this.publication != null) {
      data['publication'] = this.publication.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
        if (this.error != null) {
      data['error'] = this.error.toJson();
    }
        data['status'] = this.status;
        return data;
    }
}

class Message {
    String message;

    Message({this.message});

    Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        message = json['message'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['message'] = this.message;
        return data;
    }
}

class Publication {
    int id;
    int userId;
    String name;
    String description;
    String category;
    int quantity;
    String size;
    String brand;
    String forWho;
    String color;
    String delivery;
    String price;
    int progression;
    String discount;
    int visibility;
    String status;
    int softdelete;
    String createdAt;
    String updatedAt;
    String picture1;
    String picture2;
    String picture3;
    Null picture4;
    String picture5;
    List<Comment> comment;
    String ownerpicture;

    Publication({this.id, this.userId, this.name, this.description, this.category, this.quantity, this.size, this.brand, this.forWho, this.color, this.delivery, this.price, this.progression, this.discount, this.visibility, this.status, this.softdelete, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt, this.picture1, this.picture2, this.picture3, this.picture4, this.picture5, this.comment, this.ownerpicture});

    Publication.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
        userId = json['user_id'];
        name = json['name'];
        description = json['description'];
        category = json['category'];
        quantity = json['quantity'];
        size = json['size'];
        brand = json['brand'];
        forWho = json['for_who'];
        color = json['color'];
        delivery = json['delivery'];
        price = json['price'];
        progression = json['progression'];
        discount = json['discount'];
        visibility = json['visibility'];
        status = json['status'];
        softdelete = json['softdelete'];
        createdAt = json['created_at'];
        updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
        picture1 = json['picture1'];
        picture2 = json['picture2'];
        picture3 = json['picture3'];
        picture4 = json['picture4'];
        picture5 = json['picture5'];
        if (json['comment'] != null) {
            comment = new List<Comment>();
            json['comment'].forEach((v) { comment.add(new Comment.fromJson(v)); });
        }
        ownerpicture = json['ownerpicture'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['user_id'] = this.userId;
        data['name'] = this.name;
        data['description'] = this.description;
        data['category'] = this.category;
        data['quantity'] = this.quantity;
        data['size'] = this.size;
        data['brand'] = this.brand;
        data['for_who'] = this.forWho;
        data['color'] = this.color;
        data['delivery'] = this.delivery;
        data['price'] = this.price;
        data['progression'] = this.progression;
        data['discount'] = this.discount;
        data['visibility'] = this.visibility;
        data['status'] = this.status;
        data['softdelete'] = this.softdelete;
        data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
        data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
        data['picture1'] = this.picture1;
        data['picture2'] = this.picture2;
        data['picture3'] = this.picture3;
        data['picture4'] = this.picture4;
        data['picture5'] = this.picture5;
        if (this.comment != null) {
      data['comment'] = this.comment.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
        data['ownerpicture'] = this.ownerpicture;
        return data;
    }
}

class Comment {
    int id;
    int pubId;
    int userId;
    String comment;
    String createdAt;
    String updatedAt;
    String username;
    String userPicture;

    Comment({this.id, this.pubId, this.userId, this.comment, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt, this.username, this.userPicture});

    Comment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
        pubId = json['pub_id'];
        userId = json['user_id'];
        comment = json['comment'];
        createdAt = json['created_at'];
        updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
        username = json['username'];
        userPicture = json['user_picture'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['pub_id'] = this.pubId;
        data['user_id'] = this.userId;
        data['comment'] = this.comment;
        data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
        data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
        data['username'] = this.username;
        data['user_picture'] = this.userPicture;
        return data;
    }
}

class Error {


    Error();

    // The response for error field is unclear
}
```